# Running Time (Big-O) of Array Insertion and Deletion

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, big-o

In a typical C array, why is it it that insertion and deletion operations have O(N) as their big-O running time?

i.e. each of the following operations have O(N) running time.

- Insert after *k*th element
- Insert after *N*th element
- Remove first element
- Remove *N*th element

How does array insertion and deletion occur during execution? If we were to insert an element at the *k*th position, why would execution not simply perform a linear method of retrieval, until reaching the *k*th position, rather than accessing each element of the array?

Comment: If you can use extra variables to keep track of array size and a circular index value, such that the array is a "circular list", then insertions/deletions from the head and tail can become O(1).  Otherwise, everything has to shift as Anirudh explains below at an O(N) rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting to the element is **O(1)** because you do have random access, but after that, creating space to insert (or compacting in case of deletion) takes **O(N)** time.

**Insertions:**

```
[1,2,4,5,6]
---^ insert after this, need to move everything one step to the right.

[1,2,_,4,5,6]
-----^ insert at this location

[1,2,6,4,5,6]
```

**Deletions:**

```
[1,2,4,5,6]
---^ delete this

[1,_,4,5,6]
---^ compact to remove this "hole"

[1,4,5,6]
```

The reason is that you have to maintain the invariant that all the elements are stored at consecutive locations (necessary for random access in O(1)).

In order to have better insertion and deletion guarantees, a linkedlist is more suitable, because it requires no shifting of elements as contiguity and random access aren't its properties.